# Why am I getting this error even though I am simply intializing?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I keep getting this error for this block of code even though this is the beginning of the program and I am simply initializing. What do these errors mean?

**Code:**

```
public delegate void ProgressHandler(object myObject, CompareFilesUtilityEventArgs myArgs);
private ProfileClass _profile = new ProfileClass();
private FileClass _ComparisonFileOne = new FileClass();
private FileClass _ComparisonFileTwo = new FileClass();
```

**Errors:**

> The type or namespace name 'ProfileClass' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'FileClass' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'CompareFilesUtilityEventArgs'could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you have those classes mentioned in the errors defined somewhere? You can't just say `Dog fido`, you have to create a `Dog` type first.

Comment: Where have you declared your `ProfileClass`, `FileClass` etc classes? Are they in the same namesapce as this code is in? In not you'd have to include a `using` directive to those.

Comment: As the previous comments said...or...please post a more fuller representation of your code, maybe your entire class file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a `Console` program, of which the `namespace` is named `FirstNamespace`. You declare a `ClassA` inside this namespace. Then you have a second namespace, named `SecondNamespace`, and in there you have another class, named, `ClassB`.

Now, from inside `FirstNamespace`, if you create an object instance of `ClassA`, that will be fine, as both the `ClassA` and the calls in which the object is created (`Program` class in the example below) are in the same namespace. But if you try to create an instance of `ClassB`, the compiler will complain as it is not 'aware' of the `ClassB` which is inside of a different namespace.

```
namespace FirstNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ClassA classA = new ClassA();
            ClassB classB = new ClassB();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class ClassA
    {

    }
}

namespace SecondNamespace
{
    public class ClassB
    {

    }
}
```

Here, the line that instantiates `classB` gives me the following error:

> CS0246  C# The type or namespace name could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

To fix this, I must include a reference to the `SecondNamespace` using a `using` directive, just outside the namespace decleration:

```
using SecondNamespace;

namespace FirstNamespace
{
    ...
```

Now the `FirstNamespace` is aware of the `SecondNamespace`, and `ClassB` will be visible to it.